# Good tutorial for Google Cloud Speech API/Speech recognition on Mac/Python?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to use speech recognition for building a project, and as of now have had 0 luck doing so. When I try using the sample code provided from google: https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/master/samples/v1/speech_transcribe_sync.py I get an error **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'resources/brooklyn_bridge.raw'** and I am not exactly sure where to find this file or what it is used for. Whenever I try using speech_recognition library I get the error **OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error**.

Basically my goal is to make a chatbot where the chat bot speaks (have that part down), and then the user responds with speech which can be parsed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just copied the one file. It's best to clone the whole repository. Then the script will also find the file. Otherwise you will find the file in the [resource folder](https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/tree/master/samples/resources).